# I'm having trouble with figuring out how the following code works?

Tags: python, list

Could someone please explain why `ref_len` = `9` after it runs, and how the second line in the code shown below works?

```
ref_len_list = [9,9,5,9]
ref_len = min(ref_len_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-8))
```

Comment: This finds the closest number to 8 from the list. A number having the least difference with a number will be closer to that number than other numbers.

Comment: This looks for the number `x` for which `abs(x-8)` is minimum. For `9`, that is `abs(9-1)=1`, whereas for `5` it is `abs(5-8)=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
ref_len = min(ref_len_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-8))
```

will look for the number in `ref_len_list` for which `abs(number - 8)` has the lowest value, and thus is the value closest to `8`. From this list it gets the number `9`, because `abs(9-8) < abs(5-8)`. If there would be both `9`s and `7s` in this list, it would just give the first one of those.

So:

```
min([9,9,5,9], key=lambda x:abs(x-8))  # --> 9
min([7,9,5,6], key=lambda x:abs(x-8))  # --> 7
min([9,7,5,6], key=lambda x:abs(x-8))  # --> 9
min([7,9,5,8], key=lambda x:abs(x-8))  # --> 8
```

---

The line works by using the `min` function and passing the optional `key` argument to it. The `key` argument will specify for the function what criteria it should use when ranking the elements of the list.

In this case the `key` argument is given an anonymous `lambda` function which will take a number `x` as an argument and return `abs(x-8)`.

The function `lambda x:abs(x-8))` can be re-written as follows:

```
def func(x):
    return abs(x-8)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second line of code, `ref_len = min(ref_len_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-8))` simply looks at the first line of code, `ref_len_list = [9,9,5,9]` and finds the value closest to 8. It just picks an item from the list that satisfies the code.

Answer (score 0):

`min` picks the minimum value from the list. If given no `key` argument, it just uses the values themselves to determine what the "minimum" is (i.e. from a list of numbers it's somewhat obvious what the minimum is). Given a `key` argument, it uses that function to get the value for each item in the list that it should consider. It's *typically* mean for cases like this:

```
[{'foo': 3, 'bar': 'baz'}, {'foo': 4}]
```

`min` can't just know what value it should use here, so you'd do `min(lst, key=lambda i: i['foo'])`, which returns `{'foo': 3, 'bar': 'baz'}`, since it has the lowest value for `i['foo']` (`3`). But `key` doesn't have to get a key from a dict, it can return any value it wants. Here it returns `abs(x - 8)`, so the result is the number whose value is the smallest when subtracted from 8.